# Change color based on value from another table

Tags: excel

I have an answer sheet (in sheet tab "Answer Sheet") in Excel like this:

[image: Answer Sheet]

And I have this table for correct answers (in sheet tab "Correct Answer") like this:

[image: Correct Answer]

I want to change the color for incorrect answers with red background.

And I want to create a "toggle" to show the incorrect answers (if I change the value to "TRUE"), maybe like this:

[image: Incorrect Toggle]

How do to it?

Comment: Use `Conditional Formatting` with `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination.

Comment: could you elaborate in detail how to do it @Harun24HR? I don't really have deep knowledge using excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the conditional formatting manager:
Start => Conditional Formatting => New Rule => Based on Formula (last option)
In the Formula you will click on the answer sheet in B2 and remove the "$" type "<>" (which stands for not equal) and then select B2 in the correct answer sheet:

= B2<>CorrectAnswer!B2

Then you will then change the format to the style you like and click ok.

Edit: to extend the area the formatting applies to, you can copy the formatting by using the formatting paster:
https://www.solveyourtech.com/copy-cell-formatting-from-one-cell-to-another-in-excel-2010/
or by extending the area it applies to after you defined the rule:
https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/images/manage-rules/conditional-formatting-rules-manager.png

Toggling:
This can be done in the manager by setting it to active or inactive. https://excelunplugged.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/060314_0545_turnconditi6.png
Alternatively: you could write the formula like this:

= and(B2<>CorrectAnswer!B2;$G$9=TRUE)

Comment: so, i must do it one by one? like : 
= B3<>CorrectAnswer!B3 
= B4<>CorrectAnswer!B4 
etc ?

Comment: you can copy the formatting by using the formatting paster:
https://www.solveyourtech.com/copy-cell-formatting-from-one-cell-to-another-in-excel-2010/
or by extending the area it applies to after you defined the rule:
https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/images/manage-rules/conditional-formatting-rules-manager.png

Comment: it works! the next step is, how to make a "toggle" for it? like, if I change the value of column (let say it column G9 -- for example) to "FALSE", the color not changed.

Comment: The Toggling can be done in the manager by setting it to active or inactive. https://excelunplugged.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/060314_0545_turnconditi6.png

Comment: Did the toggle options work for you as well?